# Why TomlParseResult.get() only works with first key

Tags: java

I have a TOML file that is formatted correctly but when I want to read keys from it I can only read the first one as other give null as result even tough they have an value

```
modLoader="javafml"

loaderVersion="[14,)"


modId="optifine"

version="1.0.0"

displayName="OptiFine"

displayURL="https://optifine.net"

authors="sp614x"

description='''
OptiFine is a Minecraft optimization mod.
It allows Minecraft to run faster and look better with full support for shaders, HD textures and many configuration options.
'''
```

thus I'm confused because my code looks like so

```
TomlParseResult result= Toml.parse(Paths.get("mods.toml"));
        System.out.println(result.get("version"));
        result.errors().forEach(error -> System.err.println(error.toString()));
        System.out.println(result.getString("description"));
```